# In R how to match with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, random, merge

I need to divide data in DF1 in to groups based on their class. In some cases everything in class will be in the same group. Class needs to be divided in to groups by random, but not by equal shares. In DF2 i have the data that gives the shares how the data needs to be divided. 
DF2 is imported by me from excel. This file is mentained by me and if needed you can make changes to the structure of the data. This is the file I will use to divide the classes in to groups. Share column tells me how many of the class must be divided in to this group.  For example 50% of rows in DF1 with class 1 must be dividend in to Apples, 25% in to Hammers and 25% in to Car. 
NB! It needs to be random, it cant be that first 50% rows are Apples, next 25% hammers etc.

My solution is to give every row in DF1 a random number that I save every time i make it so i can go back and use the seed I got before. 
NB! It’s important to me that I can go back to the previouse random if a colleague or I runs the code by mistake and making a new random seed. I have that part covered in the case of the random number.

```
      DF1 (base data)          
ID   Class   Random     
1      1      0,65
2      1      0,23
3      2      0,45
4      1      0,11
5      2      0,89
6      3      0,12
7      1      0,9
```

My solution is to make a share_2 column where i divide 0-1 in to spaces based on the share column. In excel logic i would like to do the following:

```
IF Class = 1 then
IF Random < 0,5; Apples; if not then
IF Random < 0,75; Hammer if not then
IF Random <1; Car
```

```
 DF2  (Classification file made by me)
Class   Group          Share      Share_2
1       Apples        50%*        0,5
1       Hammer        25%         0,75
1       Car           25%         1
2       Building      100%**      1
3       Computer      50%         0,5
3       Hammer        50%         1

*This means that 50% of class 1 need to be "Apples". Shares in a class give 100% in total.
```

I need

```
    DF3
ID   Class   Random      Group    
1      1      0,65      Hammer
2      1      0,23      Apples
3      2      0,45      Building
4      1      0,11      Apples
5      2      0,89      Building
6      3      0,12      Computer
7      1      0,9       Car
```

My probleem is that i don’t know how to write it in R. Can you please help me. 
NB! Please feel free to offer also ohter methods of solving my problem as long as it makes the dividing of class by random and i can save the randomnes to replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this that does *not* use the random numbers you have already generated, but is otherwise fairly short, is to use the `random()` function to do the random assignment directly for you:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:7,
  Class = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1),
  Random = c(0.65, 0.23, 0.45, 0.11, 0.89, 0.12, 0.9)
)

DF1 <- DF1[order(DF1$Class), ]  #EDIT: need this for the code to behave properly!

DF2 <- data.frame(
  Class = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
  Group = c("Apples", "Hammer", "Car", "Building", "Computer", "Hammer"),
  Share = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 1, 0.5, 0.5),
  Share_2 = c(0.5, 0.75, 1, 1, 0.5, 1)
)

set.seed(12345)  # this is for reproducibility; you can choose any number here

DF3 <- DF1

DF3$Group <- unlist(sapply(unique(DF1$Class), function(x) {
  with(DF2[DF2$Class == x, ], 
       sample(Group, size = sum(DF3$Class == x), 
              prob = Share, replace = TRUE))
}))
```

Working from the outside in: the `sapply` parameter serves essentially the role of a `for` loop. It begins by looking at all the unique entries in `DF1$Class`. For each of those (called `x`), it carves out a chunk of `DF2` corresponding to the portion that has `Class` equal to `x`, and then focuses only on that chunk of `DF2` -- this is what the `with()` function is doing here.

The core idea is to use `sample()`. We draw the things to sample from the `Group` column of `DF2`, draw an appropriate number of samples (marked by the `size` parameter), set the probabilities according to the `Share` column of `DF2`, and draw with replacement. All of this makes sense because we are inside the `with()` function; we have already restricted our attention to not only `DF2`, but just the chunk of `DF2` corresponding to `Class == x`.

The `unlist()` function is used because the output of the `sapply()` function is a list in this case, and we want it just to be a vector; then, we just glue that vector directly onto the `DF3` data frame, which is otherwise an identical copy of `DF1`.

**EDIT:** I added a line sorting `DF1`, which is necessary for this solution.

Comment: This works for me! Thank you. Only problem I had that in my original DF2 i have more classes then in DF1 so it gave me an NA error. But i got around it by making a new temporary DF4 that only contained the same classes  that were in DF1.

Comment: Oops! **WARNING!** I realized that this solution does *not* work on the given data set! It relies on `DF1` being sorted by `Class`, which it is not in your example. The easy fix is to sort `DF1` by `Class`; if you don't want to do that, let me know and I can reformulate the solution. My apologies!

Comment: Specifically, what went wrong in the original version is that the vector we created *was* sorted by `Class`, so when we glue it onto the copy of `DF1`, it would have the right numbers / proportions of elements, but they might not align with the existing `Class`es -- e.g. the code I wrote originally would assign `Building` to something in `Class == 3`, which it shouldn't.

Comment: I can tested out tomorrow but I can short the DF by class prior to running the code. Order of DF lines is not important to me. Thank you for coming back and telling me about it. It probably saved me some time. I should reach the point this week when I will be done with my whole code and then i can see if the groups are in the right amount of shares.

Comment: I must say that i still don't fully understand how this code works but i will take some time to go over it function by function to understand it.

Comment: Please feel free to ask any follow up questions about the code if you have them!

Comment: Aaron I tested the code out and it seems to work. There was one strange thing. The code that you provided was part of a larger code I wrote, mostly about manipulating the data to the right shape to do what I need. I left the set.seed in front of your code. But when i started to change the seed and then wen't back to the original seed i could not get the same result the first time I ran my code. I could get it the second time I ran it in a row. Something in my code uses random also. It had a simple fix i just had to move the set.seed to the first line.

Comment: I am still baffled about what in my code uses random. It's mostly uses merge, Ifelse, changing from character to numeric, reordering columns, unique and rbind.

Comment: Aaron thank you so much for helping me with the code! I hope you share your knowledge with everyone :)

Comment: Hmm -- very interesting! At any rate, glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't like this solution since I pipe two `filter`-functions and don't know how to do it in one statement.

Using `dplyr` and @Aaron Montgomery's data:

```r
merge(DF1, DF2, by="Class") %>%
  group_by(Class, ID) %>%
  filter(Random <= Share_2) %>%
  filter(Share_2 == min(Share_2)) %>%
  select(-c(Share, Share_2)) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

gives

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Class, ID [7]
  Class    ID Random Group   
  <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1     1   0.65 Hammer  
2     1     2   0.23 Apples  
3     2     3   0.45 Building
4     1     4   0.11 Apples  
5     2     5   0.89 Building
6     3     6   0.12 Computer
7     1     7   0.9  Car
```